# Bash: Remove # from the beginning of the line if the line contains specified substring

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with dependencies. Some of the dependencies are commented (#). I want to uncomment the line, if it contains a substring `cassandra`.
So If file looks like:

```
firstdependency>=2.0.7 # comment
otherdependency>=0.8.9 # another comment
#commenteddependency
#cassandra-driver>=2.1.4,!=3.6.0 # Apache-2.0
anotherdependency!=0.18.3,>=0.18.2
```

I want a script that will only change the fourth line into

```
cassandra-driver>=2.1.4,!=3.6.0 # Apache-2.0
```

So it should check if a line contains substring `cassandra`, and if yes, check if the first character of that line is equal to `#`, and if yes - remove first character of that specific line - DONE. I have no idea how to do that. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know to start with `sed`, then it's just a matter of the right replacement command.

```
sed -e "s/^#\(.*cassandra.*\)$/\1/"
```

finds lines adhering to the following rules:

1. starting with a `#`,
2. containing "cassandra" somewhere (arbitrary sequences of characters are allowed both before and after),

stores all the rest of the line (except the `#`) in a temporary `\1` (that's what the `\(` ... `\)` do) and is instructed to replace such a line only with the latter.

If needed, this can be further improved to e.g. not look for "cassandra" after a second occurrence of `#`, but I take it that the end-line comments in your example are added by you and won't be a problem.

Example output:

```
firstdependency>=2.0.7 # comment
otherdependency>=0.8.9 # another comment
#commenteddependency
cassandra-driver>=2.1.4,!=3.6.0 # Apache-2.0
anotherdependency!=0.18.3,>=0.18.2
```

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks, I noticed that and was just submitting an edit when your comment came :-)

Comment: well done! You can also just say `^#\/.*cassandra\)`. Capturing all the rest is not necessary, since it would be printed anyway. In fact, now I see this is what gniourf^2 did!

Answer (score 1):

Simple with `ed`, the standard editor:

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^#.*cassandra/s/^#/' w | ed -s file >/dev/null
```

The command `g/^#.*cassandra/` marks all lines that start with `#` and contain the string `cassandra`, and `s/^#/` removes the leading `#` in these marked lines.

Answer (score 1):

In awk. If the record starts with a `#` and has `cassandra` on it, remove the leading `#` printing all the records:

```
$ awk '/^#/ && /cassandra/ { sub(/^#/,"") } 1' file
firstdependency>=2.0.7 # comment
otherdependency>=0.8.9 # another comment
#commenteddependency
cassandra-driver>=2.1.4,!=3.6.0 # Apache-2.0
anotherdependency!=0.18.3,>=0.18.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script should contain this only line :

```
sed -e 's/#cassandra/cassandra/' your_file
```

The regex s/// replaces one pattern by another, in this case '#cassandra" by "cassandra".

Comment: Exact, sorry. TheVee's answer is much better.